# Can a shell recognize when tmux has reattached?

Tags: tmux

When I reattach to a tmux session, I would like (I think) my shell to receive a SIGWINCH.  But it does not. :(  Is there a way for a shell to recognize that it has been reattached?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.

Do you mean the shell within `tmux`, the one you see after attaching? If so:

```
tmux set-hook -g client-attached 'run-shell "kill -s WINCH #{pane_pid}"'
```

Or the shell where you invoke `tmux attach`, the one you see before attaching? (although it makes less sense). If so, something like:

```
tmux set-hook -g client-attached 'run-shell "kill -s WINCH \"$(ps -o ppid= -p #{client_pid})\""'
```

where `ps -o ppid= -p #{client_pid}` is responsible for [getting the PID of the parent process](https://superuser.com/a/150131/432690) of `tmux attach`.

`-g` means the hook is global. Unset the hook with `tmux set-hook -gu client-attached`.

Answer (score 0):

Shell inside tmux? It should get SIGWINCH if the size has changed.

If you want to know even if the size hasn't changed you would need to either write a script that polls using tmux ls/lsp to see when a session containing the shell's pane becomes attached or hack tmux to send a signal to every affected pane on attach.